# Spark SQL is not returning records for HIVE transactional tables on HDP

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I am facing this issue on HDP setup on which COMPACTION is required only once for transactional tables to fetch records with Spark SQL.
On the other hand, Apache setup doesn't required compaction even once.

May be something got triggered on meta-store after compaction, Spark SQL start recognizing delta files.

Let know me if needed other details to get root cause.

Try this,

**See complete scenario :**

```
hive> create table default.foo(id int) clustered by (id) into 2 buckets STORED AS ORC TBLPROPERTIES ('transactional'='true');
hive> insert into default.foo values(10);

scala> sqlContext.table("default.foo").count // Gives 0, which is wrong because data is still in delta files

#Now run major compaction:

hive> ALTER TABLE default.foo COMPACT 'MAJOR';

scala> sqlContext.table("default.foo").count // Gives 1

hive> insert into foo values(20);

scala> sqlContext.table("default.foo").count // Gives 2 , no compaction required.
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you ever COMMIT your INSERT? Did you `show locks` to check whether you had pending transaction locks?

Comment: COMMIT in hive ?  yes show locks doesn't show any thing.

Answer (score 0):

Spark does not support any feature of hive's transnational tables.

Please check : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15348

Comment: You should improve the answer to quote the relevant information from your link.